# Pattern brush imperfections on PSD file. Issue with faint lines on areas of artwork

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, patterns, visual-artifacts

I created a circular motif in AI based on circles populated by a self generated pattern brush.

Having completed the work I exported the document as a PSD file to add some textures in Photoshop. On opening the file in Photoshop I detected faint lines imperceptible in AI at the point in the circle where the pattern brush motif joins.

I have tried numerous things to make them disappear but everything I have tried failed. Even making a new pattern brush along the same lines made no difference these too displayed the same artifact's when converted to PSD.

The attached file is a test file but shows the issue I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok folks, I answered this myself.

I found that if I expand the object and then unite it, the problem disappears.

Comment: you can mark your own answer for the question. and would be nice to share with us some more detail on how you achieved this. in case someone else with the same issue needs.